# Javascript append text to textarea with line break

Tags: javascript

I have a button that the user can click to merge text from 2 textareas but when they click it the text from the second textarea is added to the end of the first so it is displayed in one line. I would like to add a line break to the end line of text so the appended text is on a new line.

```
<input type="button" 
       class="copy_submit" 
       value="<< Copy"
       onclick="document.forms['merge_form'].notes1.value += document.forms['merge_form'].notes2.value;" />
```

Comment: Aren't we missing the HTML forms? `<textarea>` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include newline character before `.value` at attribute event value

```
<input type="button" class="copy_submit" onclick="document.forms['merge_form'].notes1.value += '\n' + document.forms['merge_form'].notes2.value;" value="<< Copy" />
```

Comment: Brill, will accept when it allows me, I was trying to use += instead of just + which resulted in an error

Answer (score 1):

use this snippet as boilerplate. 
first access the dom element values, then use it - write somewhere on document, or to an input..

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
  var ta1Text = document.getElementById('ta_1').value;
  var ta2Text = document.getElementById('ta_2').value;
  var res = ta1Text + "\n"+ta2Text;
  document.getElementById('ta_3').value = res
});
```

```html
<textarea id="ta_1">
</textarea>
<textarea id="ta_2">
</textarea>
<textarea id="ta_3">
</textarea>   
<button>Merge</button>
```

Comment: OP appears to be setting `.value` of a `form` element child node, not `.innerHTML`

Comment: thanks but it is a little more than I needed, all I was missing was an additional '\n' + in my code

Comment: @guest271314 i think the point is to access the value. to write it somwhere is just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: @marmeladze OP is already accessing `.value` of `<textarea>` elements. OP is trying to concatenate the `.value` of two `textarea` elements at one `textarea` element. Setting `"<br>"` as `.value` or `.innerHTML` of `textarea` will set literal text `"<br>"` as value of `textarea`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `\n` :

```
document.forms['merge_form'].notes1.value += '\n'+ document.forms['merge_form'].notes2.value;
```

Hope this helps.

```css
textarea{
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<form name='merge_form'>
  <textarea name="notes1">Textarea 1 content</textarea>

  <input type="button" class="copy_submit" onclick="document.forms['merge_form'].notes1.value += '\n'+ document.forms['merge_form'].notes2.value;" value="<< Copy" />

  <textarea name="notes2">Textarea 2 content</textarea>
</form>
```